# Create Customize layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, custom-view

How to create Customize Layout in Android? My problem is I'm displaying Images in grid view, when the user reaches the last image in the grid view, it must display the message:  "click here to View More Images"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a simple way. No need to customize layout. You can do it in this way:

OnclickListener:
if(position == adapter.getCount - 1){
   tellMessage();
}